# Get all documents from ChromaDb using Python and langchain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, chromadb

I'm using langchain to process a whole bunch of documents which are in an Mongo database.

I can load all documents fine into the chromadb vector storage using langchain. Nothing fancy being done here. This is my code:

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embeddings, persist_directory='db')
db.persist()
```

Now, after storing the data, I want to get a list of all the documents and embeddings WITH id's.

This is so I can store them back into MongoDb.

I also want to put them through Bertopic to get the topic categories.

Question 1 is: how do I get all documents I've just stored in the Chroma database? I want the documents, and all the metadata.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the source code (https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py)

You can just call below

```
db.get()
```

and you will get a json output with the id's, embeddings and docs data.

Comment: Nice. However, when I run that, I get: 

AttributeError: 'Chroma' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Ok, so probably you just need to update langchain, as get was introduced just 4 days ago. Just run 'pip install --upgrade langchain' and try again.

Comment: How do you do this in another file?

Comment: You can create ChromaDB client separately and perform any operations on collections. Please send correct persists directory

Answer (score 5):

Once the DB is created, you can create a client separately using the DB persist directory as below

```
import chromadb
client = chromadb.Client(Settings(is_persistent=True,
                                    persist_directory= <PERSIST_DIR_NAME>,
                                ))
coll = client.get_collection("<name of the collection>")
coll.get() # Gets all the data
```

You get a JSON with all embedded info, Metadata, Source and Documents as well.