# How to check number of documents in vectorstore in langchain?

Tags: embedding, langchain, large-language-model, chromadb, vector-database

```py
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=final_docs, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_dir)
```

how can I check the number of documents or emebddings inside `vectorstore`?

Answer (score 3):

`len(vectorstore.get()['documents'])`
will get you the number of documents, for instance.

Inspired by [Get all documents from ChromaDb using Python and langchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76184540/get-all-documents-from-chromadb-using-python-and-langchain?rq=2)

Comment: I don't see a `.get()` method when testing this with a FAISS vectorstore instance. Is your answer specific to a ChromaDB vectorstore?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the documents and check with len

```
all_documents = collection.get()['documents']
total_records = len(all_documents)
print("Total records in the collection: ", total_records)
```

Answer (score 0):

For FAISS.

```
faiss_vector_store = FAISS(
            embedding_function=embedding_function,
            index=IndexFlatL2(embedding_size),
            docstore=InMemoryDocstore(),
            index_to_docstore_id={}
        )
doc_count = faiss_vector_store.index.ntotal
```